# How to configure multiple exception handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to configure my middleware pipeline to use 2 different exception handlers to handle the same exception.  For example, I'm trying to have both my custom handler and in-built DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
        app.ConfigureCustomExceptionHandler();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");                               
        app.ConfigureCustomExceptionHandler();            
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

My objective is to have the custom handler do its own thing (logging, telemetry, etc), and then pass on (next()) to the other in-built handler which displays a page.  My custom handler looks like this:

```
public static class ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureCustomExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {            
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
        {
            appError.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {                    
                var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (contextFeature != null)
                {
                    //log error / do custom stuff

                    await next();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I cannot get CustomExceptionHandler to pass on processing to the next middleware.  I get the following page instead:

404 error:

[image]

I tried switching around the order, but then the developer exception page takes over and the custom exception handler is not called.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

**Update:**

> The solution was to take Simonare's original suggestion and re-throw the exception in the `Invoke` method.  I also had to remove any type of response-meddling by replacing the following in `HandleExceptionAsync` method:
>
> `context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
>   context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
>   return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);`
>
> with:
>
> `return Task.CompletedTask;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling two different Exception Handling Middleware, you may consider to add logging under your `Home/Error`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    //log your error here
    return View(new ErrorViewModel 
        { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

alternatively, you can use custom Expception Handling Middleware

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, env);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected
        var message = exception.Message;

        switch (exception)
        {
            case NotImplementedException _:
                code = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented; 
                break;
            //other custom exception types can be used here
            case CustomApplicationException cae: //example
                code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                break;
        }

        Log.Write(code == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError ? LogEventLevel.Error : LogEventLevel.Warning, exception, "Exception Occured. HttpStatusCode={0}", code);


        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        return Task.Completed;
    }
}
```

and Simply Register it inside IApplicationBuilder Method

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your suggestion is to always have a single exception handler, but I would like to keep the default developer exception page while also doing my own custom logging by leveraging the middleware pipeline.

Comment: `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` will work for you. You can have as many Middleware Handlers as you can (of course keep in mind that they have performance impack)

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include how to register the `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` side-by-side with the built-in `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` or `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error")` middleware?  I've tried implementing the class, but it still takes over the other built-in middleware completely.

Comment: Hi Simonare, thanks!  Once I understood how the middleware class worked, I managed to get it to work with a small tweak.  To pass on the exception to the next middleware in the pipeline, one simply has to rethrow the exception in the Invoke method.

Comment: Simonare, please update your answer by adding "throw;"  at the end of the Invoke's catch block, and also returning `Task.Completed` instead of `context.Response.WriteAsync(result);`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple version of how to use custom exception handling logic *WITH* the built-in ASP.NET Core error page at the same time:

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); //use standard error page
app.Use(async (context, next) => //simple one-line middleware
{
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke(); //attempt to run further application code
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //something went wrong
    {
        //log exception, notify the webmaster, etc.
        Log_Exception_And_Send_Email_or_Whatever(ex);
        //re-throw the exception so it's caught by the outer "UseExceptionHandler"
        throw;
    }
});
```

P.S. Uhmm, I added an explicit `language: c#` hint to my answer but syntax highlighting still does not see `catch` as a keyword... Interesting.